# Maximum and minimum value of $\|A\|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ real matrix. If $A$ is orthogonal, determine its maximum value and minimum value of $\|A\|_1$.

My answer:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a \quad b\\ c \quad  d \end{pmatrix}$.
From $A^tA=I$, we get $a^2+c^2=1$, $b^2+d^2=1$, and $ab+cd=0$.
Since $a^2+c^2\geq 2 \max\{|a|,|c|\}^2$, we have $|a|+|c|\geq \max\{|a|,|c|\}\geq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+c^2}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. We also have $|b|+|d|\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
Thus, $\|A\|_2=\max\{|a|+|c|,|b|+|d|\}\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
By the similar argument, we get $\|A\|_1\leq \sqrt{2}$.

How to argue that $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is the minimum value of $\|A\|_2$ and $\sqrt{2}$ is the maximum value of $\|A\|_1$?

Comment: maximum value over all such matrices? Then you just need example of  a matrix where the values are achieved- right?

Comment: @voldemort Maximum values over $2\times 2 matrix$. What is the easiest example?

Comment: I don't know how to argue about the $\max$ of $\|\cdot\|_2$ over the orthogonal $A$'s being $\sqrt{2}/2$ since $\|A\|_2=1$ for any orthogonal $A$.

Comment: Your computation is probably correct, because the constants in the matrix norm equivalences are in general sharp http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence ...